# AWS S3 - What to set KEY to?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I have been given instructions to download data from `s3://x.y.z/` using python, where x, y, z are placeholders of course.

I've gotten myself set up to run the following code

```
import boto3
import botocore

BUCKET_NAME = 'my-bucket' # replace with your bucket name
KEY = '???' # replace with your object key
LOCAL_TARGET = 'some.data'

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

try:
    s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(KEY, LOCAL_TARGET)
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
        print("The object does not exist.")
    else:
        raise
```

but all my attempts at guessing what to set `BUCKET` and `KEY` to have resulted in a 404 error.

What would the appropriate values, given the following information?

> The data has been uploaded to `s3://x.y.z/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key will be the filename you want to download for example

http://s3.amazonaws.com/goat-bucket/farms/andys/goat.png

bucket: `goat-bucket`

key: `farms/andys/goat.png`

If you don't know the object name, you can list out the object names of `goat bucket` like so:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('goat-bucket') # Using the bucket name above
for object in bucket.objects.all():
    print('Bucket name: ' + object.bucket_name)
    print('Object key: ' + object.key)
```

Would output:

```
Bucket name: goat-bucket
Object key: farms/andys/goat.png
```

Comment: So how would you infer that from the information I have available?  (The text in the yellow block)

Comment: Talk to whoever asked you to do this, they forgot to mention what file data to download. If they don't have any ask them to put a test file in the bucket for you to download. They are not providing you full information to verify that your task is complete.

Comment: I'm scared to do that, because it's a task for a job, I'm worried if I ask a question that makes me look incompetent I will be immediately crossed off the list.  So I wanted to really do my best to figure it out before I ask them anything.  I will try to guess some more :)

Comment: Ouch, sounds like a friendly environment, check in with https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Ahah! I was looking for a way to just try to guess the bucket name - Thanks for the edit, I finally got it!

Comment: Glad it worked, a little piece of advice don't get confused by the "Create Folder" Button in the AWS Management Console.  There is no concept of a folder in s3.  The object key in this case is `farms/andys/goat.png`.